# If given multiple "cases", how can I modify the previously modified variable instead of concatenating to it?

Tags: javascript

My code works fine until more than 1 "cases" are plugged in, where it simply just overwrites the previous case.

Eg. `console.log(makeCase("this is a string", ["upper", "snake"]));`
becomes "this_is_a_string" when it should be "THIS_IS_A_STRING"

I want to be able to save the new result so if there is more than one "cases", it modifies that new string instead of modifying the original string. So the code changes the original string to THIS IS A STRING, and then goes around again to make it THIS_IS_A_STRING.

Also I have the switches separated like that because part of the assignment involves this:

/* Precedence of each of the casing styles are as follows, values higher in the list should be processed first:

camel, pascal, snake, kebab, title

vowel, consonant

upper, lower */

Thanks for any help.

```
const makeCase = function (input, cases) {
  let finalCase = "";
  for (let i = -1; i < cases.length; i++) {
    switch (cases[i] || cases) {
      case "pascal":
        finalCase = pascalCase(input);
        break;
      case "camel":
        finalCase = camelCase(input);
        break;
      case "snake":
        finalCase = snakeCase(input);
        break;
      case "kebab":
        finalCase = kebabCase(input);
        break;
      case "title":
        finalCase = titleCase(input);
        break;
    }
    switch (cases[i] || cases) {
      case "vowel":
        finalCase = vowelCase(input);
        break;
      case "consonant":
        finalCase = consonantCase(input);
        break;
    }
    switch (cases[i] || cases) {
      case "upper":
        finalCase = upperCase(input);
        break;
      case "lower":
        finalCase = lowerCase(input);
        break;
    }
  }

  return finalCase;

}


console.log(makeCase("this is a string", ["upper", "snake"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the same variable to your functions that you reassign when they're called. Set `finalCase` to the initial value of `input`, then change all occurrences of `input` to `finalCase`:

```
const makeCase = function (input, cases) {
  let finalCase = input;
  for (let i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
    switch (cases[i] || cases) {
      case "pascal":
        finalCase = pascalCase(finalCase);
        break;
      case "camel":
        finalCase = camelCase(finalCase);
        break;
  // etc
```

Note that you should start `i` at 0, not -1 (because `cases[i]` won't exist).

It would probably be more elegant to create an object of functions that you can then access with bracket notation, then use `reduce` to iterate over the array of cases, transforming the string by calling the appropriate function on the object for each element of the array:

```
const fns = {
  pascal: pascalCase,
  camel: camelCase,
  snake: snakeCase,
  // ...
};
const makeCase = function(input, transforms) {
  return transforms.reduce((lastStr, transform) => fns[transform](lastStr), input);
}
```

Live example:

```js
const fns = {
  upper: str => str.toUpperCase(),
  snake: str => str.replace(/ /g, '_'),
};
const makeCase = function(input, transforms) {
  return transforms.reduce((lastStr, transform) => fns[transform](lastStr), input);
}

console.log(makeCase("this is a string", ["upper", "snake"]))
```

Another live example when just one case is in the array:

```js
const fns = {
  upper: str => str.toUpperCase(),
  snake: str => str.replace(/ /g, '_'),
};
const makeCase = function(input, transforms) {
  return transforms.reduce((lastStr, transform) => fns[transform](lastStr), input);
}

console.log(makeCase("this is a string", ["upper"]))
```

If the transformations to be applied input may be a string, not just an array, then check to see if the argument is an array first:

```js
const fns = {
  upper: str => str.toUpperCase(),
  snake: str => str.replace(/ /g, '_'),
};
const makeCase = function(input, transforms) {
  return Array.isArray(transforms)
    ? transforms.reduce((lastStr, transform) => fns[transform](lastStr), input)
    : fns[transforms](input);
}

console.log(makeCase("this is a string", "upper"))
```

Comment: Actually do you mind expanding on the reduce answer you have here? I'm trying to make it work and it just isn't working and I'm not totally sure why. Pretty new to coding in general and trying to wrap my head around reduce. The code block you gave me on its own gives me errors "case - parameter declaration expected".

Comment: Oh, I guess `case` is a keyword, so it doesn't work. See edit - use a different variable name. What `reduce` does is it iterates through an array while passing the value returned from the last iteration (or the initial value). Here, `input` is the initial value, and `lastStr` is the accumulator (the value from the last iteration). So on every iteration, a transformation made by calling the appropriate function property on `fns` is called.

Comment: Yeah actually I noticed that and changed it to basically how you have above, but then it throws a "fns[transform] is not a function" error instead.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to access a property of the object that you didn't define. You need to move *all* the functions to the object - check which transformation is being called when the error is thrown, and make sure that the object has that as a property (sounds like it doesn't at the moment\).

Comment: Oh my bad. Alright, it works up until the part where 2 transforms are given and then throws that same error "fns[cases] is not a function"

Also I appreciate the quick responses!

Comment: `cases` is an array, not a string - to access the appropriate property on the object, you need to take a value from the array (so you have the string transformation name), then look it up on the object - either with `reduce`, or with something like `input = fns[cases[i]]` when inside a `for` loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208608/discussion-between-xynon-and-certainperformance).